# Map Reduce on data that gets generated along

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce, distributed, bigdata

I am starting to learn about Map Reduce and I can't figure it out if it's going to work for the problem I am trying to solve.

From what I read, you start with a HUGE amount of data, and then you do the map and reduce steps to get a result from that data.

The problem that I am trying to solve has two phases: 
1. Generate
2. Prune

Basically when I run the program I start from scratch, with no data yet, but the generate phase writes pieces of data into files. And the prune phase removes some pieces of data that is symmetric or included in another piece of data. But this is not relevant to my question.

What is relevant is that I start from **scratch**, with 0 bytes of data, and as **the program runs** (it will run for like one week) a **huge amount of data will be generated** (GB's or even TB's of data). Can I use a MapReduce approach in this type of problem? On data that initially doesn't exist or it's very very small, but as the program runs, the data gets updated and very big in size?

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, why wouldn't you be able to?

Technically, if you have `reduce` you're turing complete, so you could run anything in a mapreduce cluster.

Oh, and you're probably going to want to quantify "HUGE".